# ArCore Augmented Images will be place horizontal on the wall

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

I am trying to make something like this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sX1aOBlwGWc
[image]

I can render an image in AR. But it always placed with the wrong orientation. What I actually want to achieve is that an image is overlayed over the current poster, picture, banner.

This is my code:

My config:

```
config.focusMode = Config.FocusMode.AUTO
config.updateMode = Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE
config.planeFindingMode = Config.PlaneFindingMode.VERTICAL
```

My code after an image is recognised.

```
ViewRenderable.builder()
     .setView(context, R.layout.ar_layout)
     .build()
     .thenAccept {
          addNodeToScene(arFragment, image, it)
     }

private fun addNodeToScene(fragment: ArFragment, image: AugmentedImage, renderable: ViewRenderable) {
    val node = Node()
    node.renderable = renderable
    val pose = image.centerPose
    val anchorNode = AnchorNode(image.createAnchor(pose))
    anchorNode.addChild(node)
    fragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
    Toast.makeText(fragment.context, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

the ar_layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/poster" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I found some tutorials on how you need to implement it in Unity. But that is not how I want to do it. Can someone help me figure this out?

What I got at this point:

[image]

Comment: ever tried `Config.PlaneFindingMode.HORIZONTAL` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried. This does not fix the issue

Comment: `layout_width="50dp"` and `layout_height="75dp"` generally define a 2/3 portrait layout. flipping these values should result in a 2/3 landscape layout.

Comment: Yes I know. but that is not what I want. I want to overlay the image on the table or on the wall. Currently the poster is sticking out of the image on table or the wall

Comment: there's even `Config.PlaneFindingMode HORIZONTAL_AND_VERTICAL`. when checking the lower image; it is anchored and perfectly aligned to the upper boundary.

Comment: what should I use? Or what settings should I enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by creating my own cube (flat cube) and adding the image as a texture.

```
fun renderImage(arFragment: ArFragment, anchor: Anchor) {
    Texture.builder().setSource(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(arFragment.resources, R.raw.sample_image))
            .build()
            .thenAccept {
                MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithTexture(arFragment.context, it)
                        .thenAccept { material ->
                            val modelRenderable = ShapeFactory.makeCube(
                                    Vector3(0.84f, 0.01f, 1.12f),
                                    Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                                    material)
                            addNodeToScene(arFragment, anchor, modelRenderable)
                        }
            }
}

private fun addNodeToScene(fragment: ArFragment, anchor: Anchor, renderable: Renderable) {
    val node = Node()
    node.renderable = renderable
    val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
    anchorNode.addChild(node)

    fragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
    Toast.makeText(fragment.context, "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the orientation of the rendered image/view/object by using setLocalRotation.

For example, in my project, I have used the below code, which makes the rendered image face directly outward from the detected image.

```
Node cornerNode;
localPosition.set(-0.0f * image.getExtentX(), 0.1f, +0.5f * image.getExtentZ());
cornerNode = new Node();
cornerNode.setParent(this);
cornerNode.setLocalPosition(localPosition);
cornerNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(-1f, 0, 0), 90f));
cornerNode.setRenderable(testViewRenderable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The AnchorNode follows the pose of the AugmentedImage and therefore, you cannot change `localRotation` or `localPosition` on this node. From [AnchorNode.setLocalRotation](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/AnchorNode): "Set the local-space rotation of this node **if it is not anchored.**"

You can change the local transform by introducing an intermediate Node:

```
                    val base = AnchorNode()
                    base.anchor = augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.centerPose)

                    val node = Node()
                    node.setParent(base)
                    node.localPosition = Vector3(0f, 0f, augmentedImage.extentZ/2)
                    node.localRotation = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(1.0f, 0f, 0f), -90f)
                    node.localScale = Vector3(augmentedImage.extentX, augmentedImage.extentZ, 0f)

                    node.renderable = renderable
```